# Insert shipping address to an existing order in Magento 2.2

Tags: magento2, database, magento2.2

I am trying to insert billing & shipping address for some existing orders.

We had a product mistakenly set as virtual product and some customers purchased it. Now I need to manually insert their shipping addresses (and maybe billing address) into the order. Is there any plugin to do this or maybe I can update in database?

I tried to create new entry in `sales_order_address` table but it doesn't work.

Any hint would be appreciated, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay so I finally figured out how to do this. To convert a virtual product order to simple product order, you need to update `sales_order`, `sales_order_grid`, `sales_order_item`, and `sales_order_address`. Change `is_virtual` to 0, add weight, change product type to non-virtual, and add address respectively.

Hope this will help someone, cheers.